# access private page in liferay 7

Tags: liferay

Im trying access to site private page by site membership users

this is my step to do :
1-create a user
2-create user group and then add user to user group
3-create site (named testsite)
4-create private page in site (in step 3)
5-add usergroup(in step 2) to testsite (in step 3)
but after login with usergroup member   show me "the requested resource was not found"

Comment: Please clarify and give more information.  Are you using friendly URL's?  What URL are you trying to navigate to?  Explain your role and permissions in more detail

Comment: this is my url : http://localhost:8080/group/{site name}/{private page name 
 }   i trying to navigate  to http://localhost:8080/group/guest/payesh . i defined one site role and add site member role and power user role to them     finally add my siterole to usergroup

Comment: what can i do for create private pages for member of usergroup in specific site?

Comment: Did you finally found a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

## Liferay 7 public private convention

**private**

```
http://localhost:8080/group/{site name}/{private_page}
```

**public**

```
http://localhost:8080/web/{site name}/{private_page}
```

Try replacing **group** with **web** and see what you get

Comment: i Test    (http://localhost:8080/group/{site name}/{private_page} and http://localhost:8080/web/{site name}/{private_page})   but i see The requested resource could not be found.

Comment: So are you testing with http://localhost:8080/web/{site name}/{private_page}
 or with http://localhost:8080/web{site name}/{private_page} (without the forward slash)?

Comment: yes i test . please tell me about steps to create private page for site in liferay 7

Comment: I'm sorry I still can't understand what you are saying.  Are you testing the links with or without that forward slash between web and the site name?  Also - I thought you already created the private page and couldn't access it?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick test that I've made, it seems to be a bug:

1. Create unprivileged user A
2. Create user group B
3. Make user A member of user group B
4. Make user group B member of Site C
5. Create a private page D in Site C
6. Log in as user A and try to navigate to D:

Result: Access Denied

Expected: Page D displayed.

I haven't checked https://issues.liferay.com for a known issue in this regard - you might want to do this and raise one in case you can't find it. Until fixed, you might need to find a workaround, e.g. script an individual site membership from the members of a usergroup. Luckily Liferay's API allows broad overrides on various levels - e.g. whenever membership to a usergroup (or site) changes, run additional code.